# What to prevent multiple toplevels from appearing in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

What can I do to prevent toplevels from appearing in Tkinter?

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()

def top_level():
    a=Toplevel()
    l=Label(a,text="yeni")
    l.pack()

    def yeni():
        root.destroy()
        os.startfile("a.pyw")
    
        top_level()
    
    bt1= Button(a,  text="Top Level",command= yeni)
    bt1.pack()
    a.mainloop()

bt= Button(root,  text="Top Level",command= top_level)
bt.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It outputs like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. If you don't want `Toplevel` windows, the obvious answer seems to be "don't create `Toplevel` windows".

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, but you shouldn't call `mainloop` for a toplevel. You only need to call it once for the life of your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is the Toplevel so `a.destroy()`